# Get form data in pre_save

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I access the form data in presave? More exactly I have a ManyToManyField (called user_list) in my models and I want to access the list from pre_save(self, obj)

I've tryed self.object.user_list and even obj.user_list but I keep getting and error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem this is my solution: I didn't use pre_save in the end and worked from validate, where you can access all the attributes.